# many to many join (same ID with different date)

Tags: sql, r, many-to-many, match, seq

I'm doing an analysis using SQL and R, I want to join two tables like below listed:

Table 1:

```
ID  date
a11 20150302
a11 20150302
a22 20150303
a22 20150304
a33 20150306
a44 20150306
a55 20150307
a66 20150308
a66 20150309
a66 20150310
```

Table 2

```
ID  date
a11 20150303
a22 20150304
a22 20150305
a44 20150306
a66 20150308
a66 20150310
```

The situation is like: Customer got called (table1) and Customer called back for more info (table two)

So what I want to do in the analysis is to:

1. Only show IDs that in both table.
2. Match table 2 date to table 1 date by:

   - Match the closest date
   - table 2 date must >= table 1 date 
     (like the example in result "a66" 20150310 is assigned to table1 date 20150310, while 20150308 is assigned to 20150308, not 20150309)

Result:

```
ID  table1 date table2 date
a11 20150302    
a11 20150302    20150303
a22 20150303    20150304
a22 20150304    20150305
a44 20150306    20150306
a66 20150308    20150308
a66 20150309    
a66 20150310    20150310
```

Is there any solutions for this many to many (but I don't want the n*m as result, I want 1 to 1) matching/join? Solution either in R or SQL will be wanted.

Thanks

Comment: If table 2 date must >= table 1 date, why are there blank spaces? in table2 date?

Comment: why `a11` has two rows? your 2.1 rule say match with closest date. `null` isnt closest date.

Comment: Can you explain your rules a litle better. Dont know why  `a11 20150302` have null and `20150303` at same time. Also why `a66 20150309    null` and not `a66 20150309    20150310`

Comment: 1. Blank space because for certain ID, table 1 have 3 records but table 2 have only 2 records... Just like called customer 3 times but customer only called back 2 times, so blank means that time customer didn't call back

Comment: The rule is more like, the match is from table 2 side, the table 2 will match its date to the closest date in table 1. And for a11, since table 2 only have one value so even if a11 have two 20150302, but I want to only match to one of them so it will show that customer only call backed once... not twice

Comment: what is your rdbms? btw if you include user name with `@KarlTian` that person get a notification. Otherwise you have to wait they check the question again. The one making the question always get a notification

Comment: So why `a66  20150309` get null? how you know table2  `20150310` isnt a reply to that one? and the one without reply is table1 `20150310`

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza, Netezza. and yeah....you made a good point... I want to show some null value because I don't want to confuse that how many times people call back

Comment: So you dont care which one I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Date1, Date2 FROM (
SELECT joined.ID,  joined.Date1, joined.Date2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date1 ORDER BY Date2 ASC) AS RowNumber 
FROM(
SELECT t1.ID, t1.[Date] as Date1, CASE WHEN t2.[Date] >= t1.[Date] THEN t2.[Date] ELSE NULL END as [Date2] 
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID) as joined 
WHERE joined.Date2 IS NOT NULL
) partitioned
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Joins the two tables on `ID` and removes the rows in `Table 2` that is not in `Table 1`. Then uses the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date1 ORDER BY Date2 ASC)` to match the closest date which is found by the `WHERE RowNumber = 1` clause.

Produces this output that is consistent with the conditions you listed:

```
+-----+----------+----------+
| ID  |  Date1   |  Date2   |
+-----+----------+----------+
| a11 | 20150302 | 20150303 |
| a22 | 20150303 | 20150304 |
| a22 | 20150304 | 20150304 |
| a44 | 20150306 | 20150306 |
| a66 | 20150308 | 20150308 |
| a66 | 20150309 | 20150310 |
| a66 | 20150310 | 20150310 |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but isn't it will make the output: 1st row of a66 become 20150308 paired with both 20150308 and 20150310? It should be only 20150308 on the table2 date column

Comment: @KarlTian edited my answer, it matches your conditions. however, the result set in your question is not consistent with these conditions.

Comment: Looks really nice, Thank you @Markmanguy. Just one more question, why in your output, column date2, the a22's result is not **20150304 and 20150305**, but **two 20150304**

Comment: @KarlTian because the closest date to `20150304` is `20150304`, not `20150305`

Answer (score 1):

I get the same result as markmanguy in R with `dplyr`. For a22, the closest callback for the 20150304 initial call is 20150304, not 20150305. You need a time component to distinguish this.

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(table1,table2,"ID")%>%
group_by(ID,date1)%>%
filter(date1<=date2)%>%
filter(row_number() == 1)

>
Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
Groups: ID, date1 [7]

     ID    date1    date2
  (chr)    (int)    (int)
1   a11 20150302 20150303
2   a22 20150303 20150304
3   a22 20150304 20150304
4   a44 20150306 20150306
5   a66 20150308 20150308
6   a66 20150309 20150310
7   a66 20150310 20150310
```

**Data**

```
table1 <-read.table(text="ID  date1
a11 20150302
a11 20150302
a22 20150303
a22 20150304
a33 20150306
a44 20150306
a55 20150307
a66 20150308
a66 20150309
a66 20150310", header=T,stringsAsFactors =F)
table2 <-read.table(text="ID  date2
a11 20150303
a22 20150304
a22 20150305
a44 20150306
a66 20150308
a66 20150310", header=T,stringsAsFactors =F)
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt solve it but is close and maybe will give you an idea

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/be3d6/10)**

```
With t_left as (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by "ID" order by date desc ) as rn
    FROM Table1 T
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 P WHERE T."ID" = P."ID")
),
t_right as (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by "ID" order by date desc) as rn
    FROM Table2
) 
SELECT t_left."ID", t_left."date", t_right."date"
FROM t_left
LEFT JOIN t_right
       on t_left.rn = t_right.rn
      and t_left."ID" = t_right."ID"
ORDER BY t_left."ID", t_left."date"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|  ID |     date |     date |
|-----|----------|----------|
| a11 | 20150302 | 20150303 |
| a11 | 20150302 |   (null) |
| a22 | 20150303 | 20150304 |
| a22 | 20150304 | 20150305 |
| a44 | 20150306 | 20150306 |
| a66 | 20150308 |   (null) |
| a66 | 20150309 | 20150308 |
| a66 | 20150310 | 20150310 |
```

Comment: Thanks!@Juan Carlos Oropeza